# How to make a route file compatible with traci method when sublane model is used

Tags: python, sumo

These are what I have done and I am looking for:
1 - I have three vehicle types. Car1, car2, and emergency.
2 - The emergency vehicle type is supposed to be aggressive one.
3 - I have defined the sublane attributes and their values in route file.
4 - I am interested in monitoring the entire network flow when different values are designated to sublane attributes respectively via python loop and traci modules.
5 - I am looking for a corresponding traci method. Does traci.vehicle.changeSublane(vehID, latDist) may be useful?
6 - What does latDist talk about? Does it have any interval?
7 - Due to my sublane features defined in the route file, is latDist compatible with other attributes?
8 - Is everything all right?

My route file is:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
    <route edges="e1 e2 e3" color="yellow" id="route_1"/>
    <route edges="e4 e2 e3" color="yellow" id="route_2"/>
    <route edges="e5 e3" color="yellow" id="route_3"/>
    
   <vType id = "emergency" vClass = "delivery" color = "red" lcSpeedGain = "1000" lcSpeedGainRight = "1" length = "6.5"
lcSublane = "2000" lcPushy = "1" lcPushyGap = "0.2" lcAssertive = "1.5" lcImpatience = "1" />
<vType id = "car1" vClass = "passenger" laneChangeModel = "SL2015" lcKeepRight = "0"  length = "5" 
accel = "3.5" decel = "2.5" sigma = "0.1" latAlignment = "left" maxSpeed = "7"  />
<vType id = "car2" vClass = "hov"  length = "7" accel = "1.5"  decel = "2.5" sigma = "0.1" latAlignment = "right" maxSpeed = "5" />
    
    <flow id = "type1" type="car1" color="yellow"  begin="5" end= "900" departSpeed = " max" departLane = "1" 
    arrivalLane = "1" probability = "0.2"  from = "e1" to = "e3"  />
    <flow id = "type2" type="car1" color="yellow"  begin="5" end= "900" departSpeed = " max" departLane = "0" 
    arrivalLane = "1" probability = "0.2"  from = "e4" to = "e3"  />
    <flow id = "type3" type="car1" color="yellow"  begin="5" end= "900" departSpeed = " max" departLane = "0" 
    arrivalLane = "1" probability = "0.2"  from = "e5" to = "e3"  />
    <flow id = "type4" type = "car2" color = "cyan" begin = "5" end = "900" departSpeed = "max"  departLane = "0" 
    probability = "0.1" from = "e4" to =  "e3"  /> 
    <flow id = "type5" type = "car2" color = "cyan" begin = "5" end = "900" departSpeed = "max"  departLane = "0" 
    probability = "0.1" from = "e5" to =  "e3"  />
    <flow id = "type6" type = "car2" color = "cyan" begin = "5" end = "900" departSpeed = "max"  departLane = "0" 
    probability = "0.1" from = "e1" to =  "e3"  />  
    <flow id = "type7" type="emergency" color="red"  begin="60" end= "900" departSpeed = " max" departLane = "1" 
      arrivalLane = "random" probability = "0.09"  from = "e1" to = "e3"  />
</routes>
```

my python code is:

```
import traci    
latDist = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]    
def run():
    traci.start(sumoCmd)
    
    for veh_id in traci.vehicle.getIDList():
        length = traci.vehicle.getLength(veh_id)
        if length == 6.5:
            traci.vehicle.changeSublane(veh_id, latDist)
        
    step = 0
    while traci.simulation.step(1000):  
        while traci.vehicle.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
            traci.simulationStep()
            step = 1
            step += 1
    traci.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()
run()
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Ali

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want to change/evaluate the different lcModel parameters like lcPushy or do you want to make the lane change yourself?

Comment: By using sublane model attributes, I have tried to generate an aggressive vehicle type in route file. I want to know there is any conflict between these definitions (in the case of aggressive type) and what the code is supposed to do by TraCI module's changeSublane(vehID, latDist)? Does this module prior to the sublane attributes defined in route file? Is it possible to use both sublane attributes in route file and the changeSublane (vehID, latDist) at the same time?